# Extracting specific data from XML and writing that data into CSV using Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml.etree

Hi I would like to extract the title and date from XML tags "title.block/short-title" and "court.date.block/court.date where attribute is judgment" into csv file from the below XML exceprt, I am new to Python and haven't done much coding in it.

Could you please advise?

This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE lrs-conv PUBLIC "-//TLRGAP//DTD LRS Conversion DTD//EN" "http://dtd-server/document-store/DTD/lrs-conv.dtd">
    <lrs-conv end-page="228" runhead="YOUNG V ALLAN" series="VR" start-page="226" version="1.12"
        volume="[1959]">
        <court.block id="7088155" version="1">
            <court.name>SUPREME COURT OF VICTORIA</court.name>
        </court.block>
        <title.block id="7088154" version="1">
            <short-title>YOUNG v ALLAN</short-title>
        </title.block>
        <judge.block id="7088165" version="1">
            <judge.group>
                <judge>LOWE</judge>
                <join>, </join>
                <judge.title>J</judge.title>
            </judge.group>
        </judge.block>
        <court.date.block id="7088156" version="1">
            <court.date.group>
                <court.date type="hearing" value="19590304">4</court.date>
                <join>, </join>
                <court.date type="judgment" value="19590306">6 March 1959</court.date>
            </court.date.group>
        </court.date.block>
    </lrs-conv>
```

I tried the below python code but it is just like a start which extracts date from one file and just prints it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\u0119342\Desktop\TEST PY\[1959] VR 226.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for title in root.iter('short-title'):
    print(title.attrib)
    print(title.text)
for date in root.iter('court.date'):
    print(date.attrib)
    print(date.text)
```

This is the out put I get

```
{}
YOUNG v ALLAN
{'type': 'hearing', 'value': '19590304'}
4
{'type': 'judgment', 'value': '19590306'}
6 March 1959
```

But would like to extract the data into csv like

```
Title               date type       date
YOUNG v ALLAN       judgment       6 March 1959
```

Comment: The XML you provided is not well formed; can you fix and repost?

Comment: I have reposted

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking about reading data from multiple XML files (as your title suggests), or are you asking about how to read data from an XML file and produce the output your text describes? They're two entirely different questions, and you can only ask one of them in this post. To ask the second, create a new question by clicking the *Ask Question* at the top of the page. Please [edit] to ask a **single question**, clearly stated, in this post.

Comment: I have changed the question to refer to a single request

Comment: Your XML is still invalid; try it on an xml validator like https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp.

Comment: XML is valid now

Comment: Can you use lxml for this? [BTW, when you respond to a user's comment to your question, you should include the user's name in the response, so he is alerted to your response: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work].